# instalação nodeJs em Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

No ubuntus o pacote Node.JS foi renomeado para nodejs pq já existia um outro pacote node.

**Como faço que o npm compreenda que nodejs já está instalado no sistema, mas o nome do diferente?**

tenho obtido o erro:

> sh: 1: node: not found
>
> npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"

Comment: Oi, eu vi que no stackoverflow gringo um cara teve o mesmo problema que você, tenta ver se aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu, você encontra  a  solução para seu problema

Comment: vou tentar...agradeço, me pareceu um pouco genérica , mas vou testar

Comment: Já tentou usar algum gerenciador de versões do node como o NVM, ao invés de instalar o node diretamente no Sistema operacional? Acho que fica bem mais simples instalar e fica muito mais fácil mudar de uma versão pra outra

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR]

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Provavelmente quando voce instalou o nodejs a partir do instalador apt-get,  o node ainda era uma versão anterior a 0.10.x, para resolver rapidamente execute o comando acima, que apenas cria um link simbolico.

Voce pode também (se quiser/puder correr o risco) tentar reinstalar tudo para tentar uma versão mais atualizada:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nodejs
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ sudo apt-get install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

O repositório do `NodeJS` para o Ubuntu está desatualizado. Remova complementamente o `NodeJS`

```
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs*
```

Depois instale via `nvm`

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.profile
nvm install node
```

Isso fará com que seja instalada a última versão do `NodeJS` e já cria a variável de ambiente dele para ser acessado de qualquer lugar.